# ValueError: time data '24:00' does not match format '%H:%M'

Tags: python, datetime, time, strptime

I'm having serious trouble converting 24 hour time to 12 hour.

```
def standard_time(t):     
    t = datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M")
    return t
```

When fed in `'24:00'` we get

```
ValueError: time data '24:00' does not match format '%H:%M'
```

I also attempt converting using %I (12 hour) instead of %H, but get an error whenever hours go over 12:

```
def standard_time(t):     
    t = datetime.strptime(t, "%I:%M")
    return t
```

Sort of stuck...

```
ValueError: time data '13:30' does not match format '%I:%M'
```

Does python have a simple 24 hour to 12 hour converter? Ideally 23:00 should put out 11:00 PM and 24:00 should not throw an error!

Comment: Why shouldn't 24:00 throw an error? That's an incorrect time. After 23:59 comes 00:00.

Comment: Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) `%H` covers `00`-`23`. `24:00` *isn't a valid time*.

Comment: The API I'm using gives me timesets like 00:00 - 24:00 for some reason...I'm just assuming all is professional :D

Comment: So just fix 24:00 manually in your method.

Comment: I am wondering what means '24:00' in your case then... Is it midnight of the following day? Then why not day+1 00:00? Your API is weird.

Comment: Its factual.com! I don't often question the pros.

Comment: @Korem not necessarily, some formats include 24 as per: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Times_after_24:00

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to give `00:00` for `24:00`. Last count in 24 hour format is `23:59` after that next value will be `00:00`.

Like if you have `23:59`, and add one more minutes in that

```
>>> a = datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 59)
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> a + timedelta(minutes=1)
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 2, 0, 0)
```

You will get next date with `00:00`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this!